# Drawing grid javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, grid, drawing

I'm doing a Tower Defense game and i have a problem that i can't wraped my head around.

The problem come when i mouse hover one cell who act as a tower. It show his range. But the way i do my drawing is not working correctly.

Here is the situation:

So let's say cell one is hover and is a tower it then show a circle around it, then the drawing loop draw the next cell which is not a tower and neither being hovered so it draw as a simple cell on top of the circle of the previous cell who is still being hovered.

The drawing loop

```
  setInterval(function(){
    for(var row = 0; row < NumberOfRow; row++){
        for(var col = 0; col < NumberOfCol; col++){
            grid[row][col].draw();          
        }
    }

},1000 / 60);
```

The method draw of each cells

```
this.draw = function(){
    if(this.isPath && this.tower == null){  
        c.fillStyle = "rgba(69,14,14,0.5)";
        c.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);   
    }
    else if(this.tower != null){
            //Draw range
            if(this.isHover){
                c.beginPath();
                c.arc((this.x + (this.width / 2)), (this.y + (this.height / 2)), this.tower.range, (2 * Math.PI), 0, false);
                c.fillStyle = this.tower.color;
                c.fill();
                c.lineWidth = 2;
            }
            //Draw the tower
            c.fillStyle = this.tower.color;
            c.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
    }
    else{
        //Draw the normal cell
        c.beginPath();
            c.lineWidth="1";
            c.strokeStyle= this.borderColor;
            c.rect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
        c.stroke(); 

        c.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
        c.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
    }

}
```

Here an image to explain

[image]

Comment: i will suggest you to mark the hovered tower co-ordinate and then first draw the whole grid and then your circle.

Answer (score 0):

like @singhisking proposed I now simply draw the tower after drawing the cell.

```
setInterval(function(){
    //draw all cells
    for(var row = 0; row < NumberOfRow; row++){
        for(var col = 0; col < NumberOfCol; col++){
            grid[row][col].draw();          
        }
    }
    //draw all tower
    for(var row = 0; row < NumberOfRow; row++){
        for(var col = 0; col < NumberOfCol; col++){
        if(grid[row][col].tower != null)
            grid[row][col].tower.draw();            
        }
    }
},1000 / 60);
```